# How do I include embed code with an external script in the body of a Gatsby site?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I'm working on my first Gatsby site and am good to go except for an embed code that needs to be placed in the body of one of the pages. I've looked at the documentation for SSR API's and can't seem to find any clear documentation as to how this is done. The code that needs to be embedded is below. Any help would be appreciated.

The embed code below only needs to go in the body of one page (not every page on the site)?

```
<style>.vagaro a {font-size:10px; color:#AAA; text-decoration:none;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.vagaro.com//resources/WidgetEmbeddedLoader/OZqnC30tDZCcT3q"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: If that goes in the body of one of the pages, you can include the script tag as a regular JSX tag, or in the mount hook or component did mount lifecicle method if you prefer to include it programatically.

If you do that tho, be careful to avoid double including the same script, it might give you odd side effects

Comment: It looks like componentDidMount might be the way to go. Thanks for the tip. I'll keep an eye out for double including.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need at add this stuff to every page, you can do this with `html.js`.

First make a copy of the existing `html.js` so that you can make persistent changes:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

Then clear the cache and public folders:
    gatsby clean

Then edit `src/html.js` with your required code before the closing of the `<head>`.

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
        <style>{`.vagaro a {font-size:10px; color:#AAA; text-decoration:none;}`}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.vagaro.com//resources/WidgetEmbeddedLoader/OZqnC30tDZCcT3q"></script>
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

---

If you only need to add it to a single page, use react-helmet

```
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

const SecondPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Page Two</title>
        <style>{`.vagaro a {font-size:10px; color:#AAA; text-decoration:none;}`}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.vagaro.com//resources/WidgetEmbeddedLoader/OZqnC30tDZCcT3q"></script>
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Page Two</h1>
      <p>Welcome to page 2</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default SecondPage;
```

Comment: Will this add the the embed code to every page? Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I need to add the code to a single page.